# Class container not working if i set a inner div to position absolute

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJyOwp

My class container , around my website menu is being ignored , it is not working, it's as if it did not exist .

I want know how can i make the menu__list, which has absolute position respect the class container, which sets the extreme of this session.

This is possible?

HTML:

```
<section class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="menu__list">
      <li class="menu__item">
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>-->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>-->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>-->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>-->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>-->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>-->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>-->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>-->
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
    <!--    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>-->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
      padding-left: 4.8%;
      padding-right: 4.8%;
      max-width: 768px; } }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
      padding-left: 4.4%;
      padding-right: 4.4%;
      max-width: 992px; } }
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0; }
  .menu__list {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .menu__list {
        width: 800px;
        height: 645px;
        margin-left: -400px;
        margin-top: -322px; } }
  .menu__item {
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .menu__item {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px; } }
    .menu__item:hover {
      background-color: #000; }
    .menu__item .fa-calendar {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      color: #000;
      line-height: 200px;
      cursor: pointer; }
      .menu__item .fa-calendar:hover {
        color: #FFF; }
```

I was trying to use position relative, but the menu__list was never centered vertically.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `position relative` to `.container`

```
.container {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  position:relative /**add this**/
}
```

Think about giving it a width and a height too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that you `.menu__list` have position absolute respect your `.container` you could add this:

```
.container {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
```